# Что получится и как это работает?(c++)

Tags: c++, строки, char

```
string c1 = "00011001"; // вот такая строка к примеру
c1[7] - '0' == ?
//и
c1[7] - '1' == ?
//и
c1[7] - 2 == ? // здесь 2 не как символ
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что получится в каждом варианте и почему.

Answer (score 5):

Спецификации языков С и С++ не специфицируют конкретных значений для символьных литералов, но однако гарантируют, что символьные литералы `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, ..., `'9'` имеют *последовательные* целочисленные значения (именно в таком порядке). Поэтому, например, значение выражения `'5' - '0'` гарантированно равно `5`.

В вашем случае `c1[7]` равно `'1'` и по этой причине

```
c1[7] - '0' == 1
c1[7] - '1' == 0
```

Чему именно равно `c1[7] - 2` сказать невозможно, ибо, как сказано выше, никаких конкретных значений для этих констант спецификация языка не оговаривает. Это зависит от конкретной платформы. Можно лишь сказать, что `c1[7] - 2` равно `'0' - 1`. (Придушенный голос из зала - "Сорок семь" - вызывает лишь снисходительную ухмылку с моей стороны.)

Comment: И все же, можно порекомендовать ТС  знакомство с повсеместно используемым  [ascii](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)